# Height of li the same in three grid column regardless of content

Tags: html, css

I've seen this asked so many times, but what I'm trying doesn't seem to be working and I just need a bit of help/pointers in what I'm misunderstanding.

I read that `display: table-cell` etc isn't the way to go if you want a fluid, responsive grid so I don't want to use that method.

I basically have a list of elements in a grid which should be three columns width.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="test_img.png" />
    <p>Some title</p>
    <p>Some content...</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The amount of `li` tags are dependent on how many items I have in my database so I never know the exact amount of items or content. But they are always in a three column grid.

My css looks like:

```
ul {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 0;
    position: relative;
}
li {
  font-size: 14px;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 100%;
   }
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

It looks like this since I'm going mobile first. So this all works fine until I hit tablet.

I'm struggling to understand how I'm able to get all the `li` tags to be the same height regardless of their content. I tried adding the `::after` pseudo selector to them and positioning the pseudo selector absolute with the parent relative but the height didn't seem to change.

Comment: Equal as in each row or all?

Comment: there is only ONE li tag (you write about "all li tags to be same heigth)?). Why do you put the p tags and the img in a ul with only one li? If you want to distribute them evenly, use a div as container (instead of ul and li) and give it "display: flex"

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596170/how-to-get-header-from-cards-or-similar-to-have-the-same-height-with-flex-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just hardcode a height and set a max-height as the same value:

```
li {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    max-height:50px;
    text-overflow:ellipsis; // in case there isn't enough room
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, but the text I get is pulled in from the database, so if the text is longer then the height it'll break the layout

Comment: Updated - you can use text-overflow if necessary and maybe a link such as "More..."

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any kind of bg color or border that would show the list item height, then you could simply clear the item after every 3rd.

```css
ul {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 0;
    position: relative;
}
li {
  font-size: 14px;
   float: left;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 33.33%;
}
li:nth-child(3n+1){ clear: both; }
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="test_img.png" />
    <p>Some title</p>
    <p>Some content...</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="test_img.png" />
    <p>Some title 2</p>
    <p>Some content...<br /><br />Even more content<br />It keeps going..</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="test_img.png" />
    <p>Some title 3</p>
    <p>Some content...<br />and more content</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="test_img.png" />
    <p>Some title 4</p>
    <p>Some content...</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The background of the body is grey, and the background of the text is white. So you can see the height of them unfortunately :(