# How to get header from cards or similar to have the same height with flex box?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

**No hacks please**

no hard coding. The idea is not solving it for one case, e.g. for the case that there is 4 columns, but solving it for dynamic content and for responsive screen sizes.

The problem to me is that it is basically not direct children, but the content of it

codepen here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxzrzV

HTML

```
<h1>disclaimer: resize the window. Make the blue headers in a row match height</h1>
<div class="row mycontainer">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala some content lala some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="item">
       <div class="header">oh no this header wraps</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 body{
  padding: 20px;
}

.item{
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.header{
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.content{
  background-color: salmon;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.mycontainer{
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

what do I want?

the blue headers to always have the same size like all elements in the current row.

a solid jquery solution is fine too... but it must be fool proof and work on resize as well. General change of structure of html is fine too. But must be responsive right.

so this (achieved by hard coding and not responsive):

[image]

Comment: Is there something missing in my answer I can add or adjust, for you to accept?

Comment: @LGSon I don't really understand the "css way" tbh, but that isn't your fault. Nice work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically 2 ways to accomplish this, the CSS way,

- [CSS - How to have children in different parents the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398498/css-how-to-have-children-in-different-parents-the-same-height)

and the script way, here using jQuery.

---

The first script sample shows how to set equal height on all items.

Second sample set equal height per row, and the way to make that work is to check the item's top value (it changes for a new row) and set the height for each processed range/row.

*I also added a couple of optimizations, preload items and so it won't process them if there is only 1 item or column.*

---

[Updated codepen 1](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxzeeG)

Stack snippet 1

```js
(function ($) {

  // preload object array to gain performance
  var $headers = $('.header')
  
  // run at resize
  $( window ).resize(function() {
    $.fn.setHeaderHeight(0);   
  });  

  $.fn.setHeaderHeight = function(height) {

    // reset to auto or else we can't check height
    $($headers).css({ 'height': 'auto' });
    
    // get highest value
    $($headers).each(function(i, obj) {    
      height = Math.max(height, $(obj).outerHeight()) 
    });

    // set the height
    $($headers).css({ 'height': height + 'px' });    
  }

  // run at load
  $.fn.setHeaderHeight(0);
  
}(jQuery));
```

```css
body{
  padding: 20px;
}

.item{
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.header{
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.content{
  background-color: salmon;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.mycontainer{
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row mycontainer">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala some content lala some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="item">
       <div class="header">oh no this header wraps</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

[Updated codepen 2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGEgvq)

Stack snippet 2

```js
(function ($) {
  //  preload object array to gain performance
  var $headers = $('.header')

  // only do this if there is more than 1 item
  if ($headers.length < 2) { return; }
    
  //  run at resize
  $( window ).resize(function() {
    $.fn.setHeaderHeight(0,0);   
  });

  $.fn.setHeaderHeight = function(height, idx) {
    // reset to auto or else we can't check height
    $($headers).css({ 'height': 'auto' });
     
    $($headers).each(function(i, obj) {    

      // only continue if there is more than 1 column
      if ($($headers).eq(0).offset().top !== $($headers).eq(1).offset().top  ) {
        return false;
      }
      
      // get highest value
      height = Math.max(height, $(obj).outerHeight()) 
      
      // did top value changed or are we at last item
      if (i != 0 && $($headers).eq(i - 1).offset().top != $(obj).offset().top) {

        // set height for row
        $($headers).slice(idx, i).css({ 'height': height + 'px' });
        
        // reset height and startIndex
        height = 0;
        idx = i;
      } else if ($headers.length - 1 == i) {
        
        // last row
        $($headers).slice(idx, i + 1).css({ 'height': height + 'px' });   
      }

    });        
  }
  
  //  run at load
  $.fn.setHeaderHeight(0,0);

}(jQuery));
```

```css
body{
  padding: 20px;
}

.item{
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.header{
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.content{
  background-color: salmon;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.mycontainer{
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row mycontainer">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala some content lala some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="item">
       <div class="header">oh no this header wraps</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

As some prefer plain javascript, I updated with such sample as well (setting equal height on all items), which apply/add a class dynamically, with the computed `height` value.

Stack snippet

```js
(function(d,t,h) {
  /*  preload some variables  */
  h = (d.head || d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);
  var items = d.querySelectorAll('.header');
  
  function resized() {
    var heights = [], i = 0, css;
    /*  delete set style so we get proper value  */
    removeElement('head_dynamic_css');
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      heights.push(parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(items[i], null).getPropertyValue("height")));
    }
    css = ".header { height: " + Math.max.apply(null, heights) + "px; }";
    /*  create and add style with height  */
    var s = d.createElement('style');
    s.type = 'text/css';
    s.id = 'head_dynamic_css';
    if (s.styleSheet) {
      s.styleSheet.cssText = css
    } else {
      s.appendChild(d.createTextNode(css));
    }
    h.appendChild(s);
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", resized, false);
  window.addEventListener("resize", resizer, false);
  function resizer() {
    if (!t) {
      t = setTimeout(function() {
        t = null;
        resized();
       }, 66);
    }
  }
  function removeElement(el) {
    var el = document.getElementById(el);
    if (el) {
      el.parentElement.removeChild(el);
    }
  }
}(document,null));
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.header {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.content {
  background-color: salmon;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.mycontainer {
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row mycontainer">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="header">bippo</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala some content lala some content lala </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div class="item">
       <div class="header">oh no this header wraps</div>
        <div class="content">some content lala </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there were some issues with  `Updated codepen 1` basically it only works if the last item is the item that makes the header wrap. I fixed that I as well added now the possibility to create 'header-groups' so that you can say "the headers must have same height, in their respective group. please give feedback or improvements as you see them https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POozLo

Comment: @Toskan Could you show me a version using the script in my `codepen 1` that _only works if the last item is the item that makes the header wrap_? .... and as I said at the previous question, not using CSS frame works like Bootstrap, I don't use jQuery either, made my own script library as well and am not familiar with all its features :)

Comment: Sorry I meant codepen 2.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eemNKq
I am thinking about creating a jquery plugin for it on github

Comment: @Toskan Thanks, missed that :), updated my answer ... when on last item, the `i` needs to be increased with 1 for the `slice` to work

Answer (score 0):

Here you have my approach with jQuery. Things get more complicated because you want you want the height of each row equal, but independent from the rest.

What I've done is use the top position of each element as a row identifier, loop through all the headers adding them a class that has this position, so later we can select a whole row using that class. In every loop, I check the height and save the max value, and when I detect we are in a new row (the top position has changed), I apply the row max height to all the elements of the previous row using the class I've assigned.

Here is the code...

```
function adjustHeaderHeights() {

    // First reset all heights to just increase if needed.
    $('div.header').css('height','auto');

    var curRow=$('div.header').first().offset().top,
        curRowMaxHeight=$('div.header').first().height();
    var n = $('div.header').length;

    $('div.header').each(function(index) {

        // Get header top position as row identifier, and add it as a class.
        var rowId = $(this).offset().top;
        $(this).addClass('rowid'+rowId);

        if (rowId != curRow) {  // It's a new row.
            $('div.header.rowid'+curRow).height(curRowMaxHeight);
            curRow = rowId;
            curRowMaxHeight=$(this).height();
        }
        else {
            curRowMaxHeight = $(this).height() > curRowMaxHeight ? $(this).height() : curRowMaxHeight;

            // It's the last header element, so we adjust heights of the last row.
            if (index+1 == n)
                $('div.header.rowid'+curRow).height(curRowMaxHeight);
        }
    });

}

$(window).resize(function() {
    adjustHeaderHeights();
});

adjustHeaderHeights();
```

I hope it helps