# Equal flexbox grid with different sized content + dividers

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I'm currently working on one .psd template and using Bootstrap 4. I have problem with one section, which contains multiple rows and columns with different content. The main problem is one column, which text, inside header, wraps into two lines. How can I center other one-lined headers inside other blocks in relation to this one?

[Image of the section from mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq3dP.png)

Additional question is about dividers. What option is better to insert them as on mockup? By using before/after?

Thanks.

```css
.benefites {
  background: #0b3b52;
}

.benefites .headline {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.benefites h4,
.benefites h2 {
  color: #92d050;
}

.benefites p {
  color: #fff;
}

.benefites .block {
  align-self: center;
}

.benefites img {margin: 10px 0;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="benefites">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="headline">Managing your team has never been easier!
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-3 block">
        <h4>Players</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Manage team roster and member profiles easily with our amazing tool</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Players</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Save time and energy! Manage all your teams in one easy-to-use platform </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Practises & Games</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p> Figuring out the “when and where” has never been easier. Schedule your games, practices, quickly and easily!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Injuries & Medical records</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Collect all the data about your player’s condition and medical records</p>
      </div>
      <div class="w-100"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Sponsors & Agents</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Manage all the sponsor and agent information with us </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Contacts</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>A full contact database that makes you easy to search, filter, and update</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Contracts</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Get full visibility and handle all the contracts online with CRM42</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Reports</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Our wide range of reports help you to take your management skills to a next level</p>
      </div>
      <div class="w-100"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Treatments</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Simply the best tool for managing all kind of team payments</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 block">
        <h2>
          And many more amazing features ...
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <h4>Customized platfrom</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Make the most out of your management tool. Create your own design quickly and easily.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" </script>
  < script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove `block` from the 1st `<div class="col-md-3">` so they all top align.

Second, as the `h4` can't see each other (not being siblings), you either need to give them a fixed height (which you can adjust using a media query for different screen sizes) or use a script.

Here is a sample using fixed height, where I added this rule:

```
.benefites h4 {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

*Here is another answer of mine, [how to get header from cards or similar to have the same height with flex box?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46600682/2827823), that has a script version, and also links to another CSS solution I made.*

Stack snippet

```css
.benefites {
  background: #0b3b52;
}

.benefites .headline {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.benefites h4,
.benefites h2 {
  color: #92d050;
}

.benefites h4 {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.benefites p {
  color: #fff;
}

.benefites .block {
  align-self: center;
}

.benefites img {margin: 10px 0;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="benefites">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="headline">Managing your team has never been easier!
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Players</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Manage team roster and member profiles easily with our amazing tool</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Players</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Save time and energy! Manage all your teams in one easy-to-use platform </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Practises & Games</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p> Figuring out the “when and where” has never been easier. Schedule your games, practices, quickly and easily!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Injuries & Medical records</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Collect all the data about your player’s condition and medical records</p>
      </div>
      <div class="w-100"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Sponsors & Agents</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Manage all the sponsor and agent information with us </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Contacts</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>A full contact database that makes you easy to search, filter, and update</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Contracts</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Get full visibility and handle all the contracts online with CRM42</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Reports</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Our wide range of reports help you to take your management skills to a next level</p>
      </div>
      <div class="w-100"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Treatments</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Simply the best tool for managing all kind of team payments</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 block">
        <h2>
          And many more amazing features ...
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <h4>Customized platfrom</h4>
        <img src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/f69f598e82ca5dd1e1603b1cc86cc39f/1517595403/422/1218424/icons.png" alt="">
        <p>Make the most out of your management tool. Create your own design quickly and easily.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Can you suggest something about dividers? For now I was able just to add them only on left/right sides, but no on the bottom of the blocks.

Comment: @mantebose As the dividers has a custom width/height, pseudo will likely be the best, and here is a sample (check notes in CSS): https://jsfiddle.net/yfomf5xq/