# Align elements in block with other elements in other block(list)

Tags: html, css

I have problem with aligning elemnts in div. I have following div:

```
<div class="lists-wrapper">
  <div class="list">
   <h4>List 1</h4>         
   <ul>
     <li>item 1</li>
     <li>item 2</li>
     <li>item 3</li>
   </ul>
  </div>  
  <div class="list">
   <h4>List 2</h4>         
   <ul>
     <li>item 1</li>
     <li>item 2</li>
     <li>item 3</li>
     <li>item 4</li>
     <li>item 5</li>
   </ul>
  </div>  
  <div class="list">
   <h4>List 3</h4>         
   <ul>
     <li>item 1</li>
     <li>item 2</li>
     <li>item 3</li>
     <li>item 4</li>
   </ul>
  </div>  
  <div class="list">
   <h4>List 4</h4>         
   <ul>
     <li>item 1</li>
     <li>item 2</li>
     <li>item 3</li>
     <li>item 4</li>
     <li>item 5</li>
   </ul>
  </div>         
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.lists-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  .list {
     width: 20%;
  }
  h4 {
    margin-bottom: 22px;
  }
  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    margin-left: -5px;
  }
}
```

I'm using React and jquery approaches doesn't work for me
The problem is that .list class blocks aligned properly to each other now but when for example h4 width is very long, it splits to the second line and ul doesn't aligned with other ul's in other list blocks because it goes down a bit because of changing the height of h4. I want alignment to work relatively to ul to other ul's in the row, is it possible to do?

Comment: i don't understand your issue. please add a image and show the your issue.

Comment: I am quite confident there's no need for JS here, but I can only guess what OP is trying to achieve, because I have no idea what the actual question was even after reading through it 3-4x. If you have problems with explaining the problem, definitely include a sketch.

Comment: I added image with the problem that I mentioned @NemanjaGlumac

Comment: This is one line of css. Add `min-heigth: 40px;` to `h4`. You can determine min-height based on your font-size and line-height. No need for absolute positioning etc.

Comment: your codes is wanting. look: https://codepen.io/dgknca/pen/zyOWWB?editors=1000 add the all.

Comment: @NemanjaGlumac I cannot use min-height because list-wrapper is responsive, on some screens very long titles is ok, o other's it splited down

Comment: Why don't u use table?

Comment: @DogukanCavus doen't understand

Comment: I cannot use table here, number of lists are dynamic

Comment: the width can be limited, on some screens there are 5-8 lists in the row, on others it can be 3-4 lists in row

Comment: @rick1 then you need to use either overflow with scroll or something like this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: no I do not need any scroll. Check @zer0 solution, it is almost what I need but it is probably for consistent number of items but not dynamic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get header from cards or similar to have the same height with flex box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596170/how-to-get-header-from-cards-or-similar-to-have-the-same-height-with-flex-box)

Comment: @ReSedano I checked code examples that you send. It isn't duplicate and I didn't find solution there.

Comment: @rick1 Ok, it was only a hint to try to help you.

Comment: @ReSedano thank you. I tried to refactore jquery into working react but without success for now.