# Equal Height with FlexBox (next level)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create equal height items inside a column. It's easy when i only have the title and price. The i can just flex grow the title, and i go my equal height.
The issue is when i also have a description.
Title
Price
Desc
There are two example, because i've tried both.
One example with all content inside one item, and the another example where the content is splittet into two item.

I've a equal height jQuery script, but want to use Flex if possible.
There's colors on all elements to see if the have equal heights.

I've my code on codepen, but i'll paste it in here also.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}
.container:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.container ul {
  margin: unset;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 32%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: .3em;
}
.container ul li h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.container.one ul li a {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.container.one ul li a h2, .container.one ul li a p {
  background: pink;
}
.container.one ul li a span {
  background: lightblue;
}

.container.one .loop--item * {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container.one .loop--item--product-link {
  height: 100%;
}
.container.one .loop--item--product-link h2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.container.two .title-price {
  background: green;
}
.container.two .desc {
  background: blue;
}
.container.two ul li a {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.container.two ul li a h2, .container.two ul li a p {
  background: pink;
}
.container.two ul li a span {
  background: lightblue;
}

.container.two .loop--item--product-link {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.container.two .loop--item--product-link div.title-price {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
.container.two .loop--item--product-link div.title-price h2 {
  flex: 1;
}
.container.two .loop--item--product-link div.desc {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Equal height: Title, Price, Description</h1>

<!-- Container ONE -->
<div class="container one">
  <h1>Content in same box</h1>
  <ul class="loop">
    <li class="loop--item">
      <a href="#" class="loop--item--product-link">
        <h2>Overskrift</h2>
        <span>17.000 kr. - 24.000 kr.</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo repellat inventore aspernatur ad quia fugiat facere rerum sapiente odit maiores!</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="loop--item">
      <a href="#" class="loop--item--product-link">
        <h2>Her er en overskrift som er lidt længere</h2>
        <span>17.000 kr. - 24.000 kr.</span>
        <p>elit. Nemo repellat inventore aspernatur ad quia fugiat facere rerum sapiente odit maiores!</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="loop--item">
      <a href="#" class="loop--item--product-link">
        <h2>Her er en overskrift </h2>
        <span>17.000 kr. - 24.000 kr.</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo repellat inventore aspernatur ad quia fugiat facere rerum sapiente odit maiores!</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- Container TWO -->
<div class="container two">
  <h1>Content in two boxes</h1>
  <ul class="loop">
    <li class="loop--item">
      <a href="#" class="loop--item--product-link">
        <div class="title-price">
          <h2>Overskrift</h2>
          <span>17.000 kr. - 24.000 kr.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetit maiores!</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="loop--item">
      <a href="#" class="loop--item--product-link">
        <div class="title-price">
          <h2>Her er en overskrift</h2>
          <span>17.000 kr. - 24.000 kr.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo repellat inventore aspernatur ad quia fugiat facere rerum sapiente odit maiores!</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="loop--item">
      <a href="#" class="loop--item--product-link">
        <div class="title-price">
          <h2>Her er en overskrift</h2>
          <span>17.000 kr. - 24.000 kr.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo repellat inventore aspernatur ad</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't....there is **NO** CSS mechanism to equalise heights of elements that do *not share a parent*. You will need Javascript.

Comment: That's sad... So when it's more than two items i have to use JS... The jQuery script that i have is pretty long. Do you have a nice js script you can share?

Comment: If you want to improve an existing script *that's a separate question*. I'd suggest that it *might* be better placed on CodeReview.SE though...but check their guidelines first.

Comment: Here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46596170/how-to-get-header-from-cards-or-similar-to-have-the-same-height-with-flex-box/46600682#46600682

Comment: @Paulie_D But you can make the li and a kind of disappear, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

As Paulie_D says, there is no way in the CSS to do it unless the elements share a parent.
In modern browsers, however, you can *flatten* your DOM tree, and make some elements disappear using display: contents.

One posible solution using this approach (getting rid of **li** and **a**)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.container ul {
  margin: unset;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.container ul li,
.container ul li a {
  display: contents;
}

.container ul li h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.container.one ul li a h2 {
  grid-row: 1;
  background: pink;
}

.container.one ul li a p {
  grid-row: 3;
  background: pink;
}

.container.one ul li a span {
  grid-row: 2;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Equal height: Title, Price, Description</h1>

<!-- Container ONE -->
<div class="container one">
  <h1>Content in same box</h1>
  <ul class="loop">
    <li class="loop--item">
      <a href="#" class="loop--item--product-link">
        <h2>Overskrift</h2>
        <span>17.000 kr. - 24.000 kr.</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo repellat inventore aspernatur ad quia fugiat facere rerum sapiente odit maiores!</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="loop--item">
      <a href="#" class="loop--item--product-link">
        <h2>Her er en overskrift som er lidt længere</h2>
        <span>17.000 kr. - 24.000 kr.</span>
        <p>elit. Nemo repellat inventore aspernatur ad quia fugiat facere rerum sapiente odit maiores!</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="loop--item">
      <a href="#" class="loop--item--product-link">
        <h2>Her er en overskrift </h2>
        <span>17.000 kr. - 24.000 kr.</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo repellat inventore aspernatur ad quia fugiat facere rerum sapiente odit maiores!</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should mention the support for `display:contents` which is virtually **nil**.

Comment: This is nice.! I'll try play with that and come back to you :)